# Django images found but not displating

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django views to display some images in a folder. The program is able to search for the files but not able to display, there is a 404 error for all the images.

views.py

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
image_now = now.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
image_list=[]
app_static_dir = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'index'),'static'),'{}'.format(image_now)),'demo')
for file in os.listdir(app_static_dir):
    if file.endswith("1_plate.jpg"):
        image_list.append(file)
```

html

```
{% for file in image_list %}
    <img src="{{ file }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Don't you need `<img src="{% static {{ file }} %}" alt="">` ?

Comment: can you display the image statically if you put the whole path in src.

Comment: @elsadek yes. I can display the images

Comment: @ADKM then you should prepend the the "file" with the correct path string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`{% static %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) to prepend the correct static root directory.

```
{% load static %}
{% for file in image_list %}
  <img src="{% static file %}" alt="" />
{% endfor %}
```

You also have to configure the staticfiles app correctly as described in the docs:

[Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)